# Hard Integration of rational fraction

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

For $j=0...n$ let be $a_j,b_j,c_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$B_j^n=\binom{n}{j}t^j(1-t)^{n-j}$$ the j-th Bernstein polynomial defined over the closed interval $[0,1]$.
Any hint on how to find a closed form solution for:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n a_jc_kB_j^n(t)\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}B_k^n(t)}{(\sum_{j=0}^nb_jB_j^n(t))^2}dt$$

Comment: 1) What is your motivation for that ? Computing lengths or areas of NURBS ? 2) As it is the integration of a rational function $N(t)/D(t)$, there is a systematic algorithm using *partial fraction decomposition* in the case of numerical values. But for litteral values, surely, nothing can be said.

Comment: 1) Yes, I need to compute the signed area subtended to a Bezier segment. 2) I noticed that the numerator is a 2n-1 degree polynomial and the denominator in a 2n-degree polynomial. Moreover, the numerator is almost the derivative of the denominator, except for those $a_jc_k$ instead of $b_j$

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace "polynomial" by "rational" in your title.

Comment: For the particular case of a cubic Bezier (the most current type of Bezier curve), see [here](https://github.com/Pomax/BezierInfo-2/issues/238)

Comment: Thank you Jane! Unfortunately I will handle with Bezier curve of any degree and a more general formula will be more helpful

Comment: OK. Remark: I am not a female. My christian name begins by Jean, which is John in english and Giovanni in italian.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo :(

Comment: The problem with the link you shared is that I need to handle with RATIONAL Bezier curve, so we have a denominator with a linear combination of Bernstein polynomials and the proposed formula does  not hold..

Comment: I was thinking to it. You have seen that my first reaction was to mention NURBS. But as you where using plainly Bezier in your comment... I am fairly certain that no general formula can be attained. Aren't you interested by numerical solutions which can give you a very good approximation ?

Comment: I already have a method that gives me a good approximation of the area. For non-rational Bezier segment I found a closed form solution, but not for the rational case :(